# My Plot is empty when I run code

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
ee = 0.5;
g = 0.1;
gs = Sqrt[g];
f = (Sin[gs*x])^2;
low = gs*Pi/2 ;
up = -low ;
ode = { y''[x] + (2ee - f/g)*y[x] == 0 , y[low]==0 , y[up]==0 } 
sol = NDSolve[ode, y[x], {x, low , up}] 
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, low, up}]
```

Boundary conditions are y[low]=y[up]=0. But when I plot this, it shows an empty plot.

Comment: `{low, up}` == `{0.496729,-0.496729}` and I think that is a problem. If I put a minus sign in front of each of those and then replace your `Plot` with `Table[y[x]/.sol,{x,-low,-up,.1}]` then it shows `{{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.},{0.}}` and I think that is a problem.

Comment: How to fix this ?

Comment: `low= -gs*Pi/2;` might help. `sol=NDSolve[...][[1]]` might help. If `y[low]==0` then `y''[low]+ (2ee-f/g)*y[low]==0` and that means `y''[low]==0` then perhaps that means `y''[x]==0` and that might explain why your `sol==0` everywhere. Are you positive your ode is exactly correct? I would start with checking that very very carefully. And look at the result using `Table` to see some of the result which might otherwise be hidden by the x axis.

Comment: Yeah, ODE is correct. Theoretically I can get desired plots.

Comment: Practically, with an example ODE, your code can get plots. `low=-0.496729; up=-low; ode={y''[x]==y[x],y[low]==-1,y'[low]==1}; sol=NDSolve[ode,y[x],{x,low,up}][[1]]; Plot[y[x]/.sol,{x,low,up}]` but I think you need something that says `y''[low]!=0`

Comment: are you getting a cup up trend for that boundary condition? because that is what we expect to get

Comment: I did nothing more than use your code with the few small changes I described earlier and I made up a random ODE that had nothing to do with what you were doing. I did that to try to show that most of the structure of your code was correct and working.

Comment: If you use exact parameters, `DSolve` returns an exact solution $y=0$: `ee = 1/2;
g = 1/10;
DSolve[ode, y[x], x]`. Inspection of the general solution `DSolve[First@ode, y[x], x]` shows it's the only solution, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
ee = 1/2; 
g = 1/10; 
low = (-Sqrt[g])*(Pi/2); 
up = -low; 
ode = {Derivative[2][y][x] + (2*ee - Sin[Sqrt[g]*x]^2/g)*y[x] == 0}
sol = FullSimplify[DSolve[ode, y[x], {x, low, up}]]
```

(I changed low to -low...) you can get a symbolic result in terms of Mathieu functions. Using your boundary conditions y[x] is zero.

Edit:

"12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

When I execute the above code using a FRESH kernel I get

```
(* {(1 - 10*Sin[x/Sqrt[10]]^2)*y[x] + Derivative[2][y][x] == 0}
{{y[x] -> C[1]*MathieuC[-40, -25, x/Sqrt[10]] + 
C[2]*MathieuS[-40, -25, x/Sqrt[10]]}} *)
```

Comment: dsvar: "-\[Pi]/(2\Sqrt[10]) cannot be used as a variable" this error is appearing.